# Searching all scheduled commercial flights

Tags: air-travel

Is there a way (similar to Google Flights / Matrix Airfare / ...) that allows me to search for all commercial flights? I'd like to have even the ones that are fully booked included. I'd assume that Google/Matrix/Skyscanner/... will not even show you a flight that cannot be booked anymore?

I don't necessarily need connecting flights, so if it only showed non-stops that'd be good enough.

EDIT (thanks to a question): Why do I want this info? Basically I have two use-cases where I found myself wanting this information:

1. In certain cases you can actually get a ticket for a flights that's officially sold out if you phone up the airline. But it'd be important to know what airline and what flight.
2. For travel planning it's sometimes important to see a "typical" flight schedule from one city to another. For example if you know you want to go to place X but you don't know whether to go to place A or B before X. Then I, it'd be nice to be able to find current, historic and future planned flights just to get an idea.

Comment: Do you have examples of flights you know are fully booked? It's not easy to check if a tool returns those without knowing one. Also note that some commercial flights are not available via generic tools, especially those of some LCCs. Are you interested in a specific market? How far in the future do you need info?

Comment: [This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/is-there-a-flight-search-engine-that-has-an-option-to-show-full-flights) is the same, but it's very old (over 10 years old!) so I'm not sure if the answers there are still valid.

Comment: [This site](https://www.wego.fr/en/schedules) seems to be able to show "schedules" rather than "availabilities", however I can't confirm if that info is complete/accurate.

Comment: @jcaron Sorry, don't have current examples.

Comment: Use case 1: Why do you want to do that? Almost sold out flights tend to be the most expensive ones. Also: airlines have no problem over-booking flights online, so getting a ticket for a full flight is unlikely. Some airlines also charge extra for booking over the phone.

Comment: Use case 2: you don't need the full data base for that. If you know your cities you can use sites like flightconnections.com to quickly see what cities are being served, who is serving them and what the timetable looks like

Comment: @Hilmar I think OP's need is not so much to get the full data at once, but rather just to be able to look up all flights (on a particular route), including both available and fully booked flights, i.e. get access to schedules rather than availabilities/fares.

Comment: For use case 1, unless you have a specific contract or status with the airline, it is unlikely the airline will make a difference between channels. If you can book it directly with them, you can book it via third parties or via their website. If it's related to a specific contract or status, if you're lucky their own website/app will show you those when connected with your account.

Comment: For use case 2, you are extending things a lot if you are including both current, future and historic. For historic see the usual tools for this (flightaware, flightradar24, etc.). For current (i.e. today and a few days in the future), those usually work as well. For future, you need to get access to airline schedules, but those change quite often, even after publication. The days of the printed schedules booklets valid for a year or a season are long gone...

Comment: I think this question is academically (or technically) interesting, but is completely not useful in the real world. I downvoted the question.

Comment: Matrix has a flag 'only show flights with available seats'. Just don't check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are ways of doing this, but it's highly unlikely that you're going to find them available to the general public for free.

All scheduled airline operations live in the OAG, which used to publish a yearly paper guide which anyone could purchase and look up schedules. Now that information lives online and one can buy a subscription and get access to the data (here, if anyone is curious: https://www.oag.com/airline-schedules-data).

There are numerous other companies which buy that data from OAG and republish it in various formats with various filters and layers (DIIO by Cirium is a popular one in the industry). Many of these can also be purchased (usually on a subscription basis) by interested individuals. I can't state definitively that you *won't* find this information for free online somewhere, but I don't find it likely, given the cost to the original purchaser.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer but too long for a comment:

At the moment me writing this, there are 11,540 commercial flights in the air. The average is around 115,000 flights per day. The exact timetable changes substantially day to day (but less so from week to week), so the amount of data required to cover, say, an entire year would very large.

What problem are you trying to solve exactly would you be doing with this massive amount of data?

There are probably commercial interfaces/databases available that OTA and search sires use, but these will cost you a pretty penny and it's also not clear whether that would address your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I'll post an edit: I want to find sold-out flights because in certain cases you can still get a ticket for them when you actually call up the airline.